# Conflict between package polyglossia and reledmac?

Tags: footnotes, polyglossia, reledmac

I looked for an existing question about this, but didn't find one, so I thought I'd make a post. I'm wondering if there is a conflict between the packages *polyglossia* and *reledmac*. Specifically, I believe that using *polyglossia* alongside *reledmac* can cause an erroneous warning message if you have *reledmac* familiar footnotes inside of a poetic stanza.

The warning message in question reads as follows:

> The number of the footnotes in this section has changed since the last run. You will need to run LaTeX two more times before the footnote placement and line numbering in this section are correct.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{perpage}

% >>>>>> THESE LINES CAUSE AN ISSUE WITH RELEDMAC <<<<<<<
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainlanguage{english}
% >>>>>> THESE LINES CAUSE AN ISSUE WITH RELEDMAC <<<<<<<

\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\colalignX[A]{\RaggedRight}
\hsizetwocolX[A]{0.48\hsize}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}
\setstanzaindents{2,1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{30pt}
\numberlinefalse

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\stanza
    Now is the time for all good men&
    To come \footnoteA{This is a footnote}to the aid&
    of their country.\&
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

If you compile this as-is, you see the warning message on first compile, and as expected, it disappears on subsequent LaTeX compiles.

However, if you uncomment the three highlighted lines (i.e., the *polyglossia* lines), the warning message doesn't go away even after repeated compiles of the example.

This MWE doesn't actually produce multiple pages of footnotes. However, if you extend it to produce multiple pages, after several compiles, the per-page footnote numbering seems correct in the PDF output, even though the *reledmac* warning message says otherwise. So I really think the message is erroneous.

I prefer to work within the bounds of a package as designed, and don't want to modify or override commands from the package unless the package docs recommend such. So my question is: Is there a good way to eliminate this error message, as it occurs so frequently in my compilation output that it makes it very difficult to see any other warning messages I might have.

Comment: Try deleting the *aux file (unless absolutely necessary).

Comment: Interesting. Looks like a (harmless) messaging issue to me: the warning is displayed although there's no actual conflict or error there (as you note, all footnotes are obviously stable from run 2 onwards). – Somewhat related: I recommend [`latexmk`(or the like)](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-make) if you're not using it already. It takes care of runs of compilation for you (even of other programs: bibtex, makeindex...) until a stable document is reached. That's especially relevant for `reledmac`, where multiple runs are needed (I routinely compile documents that need 9-10 runs...)

Comment: @rallg I'd say the .aux files *is* absolutely necessary to produce the document (to get correct references, tables of contents, and everything else). Otherwise it's back to square 1 with every compilation.

Comment: @marquinho I believe it is a harmless messaging issue...sort of. However, the message does not occur only once, it occurs every time there is a footnote in a stanza. The result is that I get a hundred or so of these messages in my output, which makes it very difficult to pick through and locate any actual issues or warnings in my compile. That's why I was hoping for a workaround.

Comment: @marquinho With something like this, I usually hope that someone will point out that I'm doing something wrong, which then leads to a resolution. However, if you think that this really is a bug in reledmac (albeit a minor one) then I should probably log an issue with the package maintainer.

Comment: imho it is bug in reledmac. polyglossia is not relevant, it happens with luatex. It looks as if \footnotelang@lua advances \insert@count to often.

Comment: @Jeff: Oh, now I get it, sorry. I assumed from your question (and the MWE) that it did appear only once at the end of the .log, but once per footnote sounds extremely annoying and actually harmful.

Comment: It certainly has to do with `\numberlinefalse` (from `reledmac`). I compiled with  `XeLaTeX`, shortened your preamble to: `\documentclass{book}` `\usepackage{reledmac}`  `\usepackage{polyglossia}\setmainlanguage{english}`  `\setstanzaindents{2,1}\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}`  `%\numberlinefalse`; the message issue occurs only when **both** the `polyglossia` block **and** `\numberlinefalse` are active.

Comment: @marquinho That's very interesting. I'll experiment and see if I can find a workaround where I leave \numberlinefalse out of my preamble. Based on what Ulrike Fischer said though, it sounds like perhaps I should log a bug with the maintainer of the reledmac package.

Comment: I think for my purposes, invoking something like `\firstlinenum{100}` instead of `\numberlinefalse` will achieve the same result. Thank you for pointing out the significance of the `\numberlinefalse` call!

Comment: Thanks for the observation @UlrikeFischer, sorry I didn't get it at first. The issue happens with polyglossia (as reported by Jeff) and with luatex without poly, as reported by you; @Maïeul might want to look at both `\footnotelang@lua` and `\footnotelang@poly` which contain an `\advance\insert@count`. Or maybe at `\normalbfnoteX`, where those two are invoked and are followed by a second `\advance\insert@count` (redundant???)

Comment: As explained on reledmac handbook, `numberlinefalse` should not be used anymore. It is too complex to maintain.